# Find out the current topmost window on Win 8 (Metro/Non Metro)

Tags: winapi, com, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I need to find the current top most window on Windows 8.
Using EnumWindows is pointless as it only returns the current windows in Desktop mode.
There however is a COM class IMetroMode which allows me to find if the "Start Screen" (Metro Launcher) is active or if the given Desktop is in Metro mode. IMetroMode->GetMonitorMode.

Is there any way to find out the current active Metro App in case the desktop is in Metro mode?

Comment: Keeping in mind the Metro sandbox, supposing you could even find it, what would you do to it?

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the window when you find it?  Apps in desktop mode should not be interfering with apps in the Metro style interface.

Comment: I dont really want to do anything to the app. what i want to do is write a program that captures the screen for selective applications.
In case the metro mode app is on top there is no way for me to make the decision.

Comment: If you want to know whether the selected application is foreground, just call GetForegroundWindow and see if it's the window you want to capture.